# Download .html file as attachment instead of opening

Tags: html, email, attachment

When I send a .html file as an attachment it opens in a new browser tab when it is clicked on. I want it to download as normal attachments are.

Is there a solution to this problem. Perhaps a programming solution? Or perhaps a file extension that downloads from emails but opens normally in a browser when clicked on?

I know that the recipient can right click and click download or something but I want the sender to be able to control whether or not it is downloaded or opened in a new tab.

Does a file extension that opens with browsers by default but downloads normally from emails exist?

Answer (score 1):

Your webserver is sending a content-type header of type "text/html", and your clients' browsers are acting on that header. If you can tell your server to send "application/octet-stream", then the browsers will ask the users what to do with the file.

Comment: I didn't understand fully. If I send a .html file as an attachment to an email on yahoo.com, how can I change the content header type? Is it part of the .html file?

Comment: Yahoo won't allow you to change the attachment content-type header. You might be able to include it as a meta-tag in the html attachment. Try putting this in the HEAD block of the html: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/octet-stream">

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing the file extension to `.php` might work. PHP files are basically html files, but they expect PHP code in there - doesn't mean there has to be though. (This may work for other code language extensions too).

Not sure if the whole workflow will play out the way you want it, but worth a try...